# replicate behavior of %f, %g and %e using stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream, qstring, format-specifiers

I am trying to replicate the behavior of %f, %g and %e using stringstream.
I have tried to write a basic api similar to what QT provides,

```
QString::number(double n, char format = 'g', int precision = 6);

std::string getCLocaleString(double value, char formatSpecifier, int precision = 6)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.imbue(m_locale); //m_locale is "C"
    if (formatSpecifier == 'f')
    {
        ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(precision) << value;
    }
    else if (formatSpecifier == 'g')
    {
        double fraction;
        int exponent;
        if (precision == 0) 
        {
            precision = 1;
        }
        fraction = std::frexp(value, &exponent);
        std::stringstream temp;
        if ((precision > exponent) && (exponent >= -4))
        {
            ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(precision - 1 - exponent) << value;
        }
        else
        {
            ss << std::scientific << std::setprecision(precision - 1) << value;
        }
        
    }
    else if (formatSpecifier == 'e')
    {
        ss << std::scientific << std::setprecision(precision) << value;
    }
    else
    {
        ss << "Invalid formatSpecifier";
    }
    return ss.str();
}
```

While this works for %f, %e also (except precision 0 on windows). while I know I haven't handled the trailing zeroes
and other such cases but for %g it doesn't seem to work even for some cases where trailing zeroes would not affect.
My first question is, Is there any API similar to this in the standard library (preferably < C++11).
If not how can I get the same behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: really curious: Why are you doing this? Going from a typesafe `opeator<<` back to format string typing seems like a step back

Comment: "preferably < C11" do you mean < C++11 or really C11 ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 yes C++11

Comment: [The fmt library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), used as base for the C++20 formatting features. And compatible with C++03.

Comment: the problem is related to decimal seperator. in some locales the decimal seperator is comma instead of a dot and so fprintf formats the double values according to LC_NUMERIC env variable (1,23 instead of 1.23) so i want to convert these double values to string according to standard C locale using stringstream::imbue() and then dump those string into file using fprintf()

Comment: sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Really not sure, but I'd expect that you can select between `.` and `,` also with `stringstream` in a simpler way

Comment: this might help for your original problem https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct

Comment: yes i have used [imbue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/imbue) to always use C locale (dot seperator) in stringstream. but i have to handle conversion of different double formats (%f, %g, %e) while converting to stream, same way as QT converts a double to Qstring using API `QString::number(double n, char format = 'g', int precision = 6)` .